# Detect OS Language & Provide Different Language Dropdown Menu

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a small application to update user's details in Active Directory. The application works fine in English. But I now want to modify it to start using it for French, Italian & German users. So I'd like to be able to detect the OS language, and then provide the existing dropdown options in those languages. I should probably also translate the select box & input box labels into those languages as well.

I think once I've detected the OS, I can just set the select options as variables, i.e. if language = EN, then select1 = English_Option1... elseif language = FR, then select1 = French_Option1 etc

What is the best method for OS detection using VB.NET/Visual Studio 2012, with an app targeted to .NET 3.5 framework?

Comment: Too broad, see [Microsoft .NET Internationalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096.aspx) for a few pointers.

Comment: @CodeCaster Through nitpicking the question simply seems to be asking how to detect the OS language.

Comment: Looking online there is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` which when I run it gives me 'en-GB' which seems right. Is this correct? I could use it to get 'fr-FR', 'de-DE' and 'it-IT'. However, also looking online, some samples have multiple forms, one for each language, and then choose which form to load based on the language detection, rather than setting differnet variables in a single form. Which is the best method?

Comment: @BenBlackmore See my answer, I also added an example of how you *could* do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name`to get the language's code, for example:

- French: `fr-FR`
- German: `de-DE`
- Spanish: `es-ES`

You would probably want to have a 'select language' form shown the first time the application starts up, *but* have it automatically highlight the OS' language.

One form for all languages should be sufficient, but however it might be an idea to create a language *class* for each supported language.

Most major programs (usually games) use language packs, and reference a word or sentence such as `@m_Welcome`; these variables are preset depending completely on the OS' language.

You might want something similar to this:

```
Private m_Start As String
Private m_helloMessage As String 'We obviously want to declare this first so it can be accessed.

Private Sub SetLanguagePack()
    Select Case (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
        Case "fr-FR"
            m_helloMessage = "Bonjour là, accueillir." 'Hello there, welcome.
            m_Start = "Cliquez ici pour commencer." 'Click here to start.
            Return
        Case "de-DE"
            m_helloMessage = "Hallo, willkommen."
            m_Start = "Klicken Sie hier um zu starten"
            Return
    End Select
    'If the OS' language isn't supported, then default to English.
    m_helloMessage = "Hello there, welcome."
    m_Start = "Click here to start."
End Sub
```

Note that you also need to import the System.Threading namespace with `Imports System.Threading` to access `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name`.