# How to edit HTML with CSS?

Tags: html, css

As I'm having my website edited in one of the web editors, I'm unable to access some of the files to edit the HTML myself. I read lots of topics on how to alter HTML with CSS, but in this case those didn't work.

This is the HTML generated with Chrome's inspector (again, I can't access this HTML in the editor):

```
<table id="wsite-com-checkout-list">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="wsite-com-checkout-list-item" colspan="2">Items</th>
        <th class="wsite-com-checkout-list-price">Price</th>
        <th class="wsite-com-checkout-list-quantity">Quantity</th>
        <th class="wsite-com-checkout-list-total wsite-align-right">Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

So I'd like to have words Items, Price, Quantity and Total translated to another language, how do I do it?

One another example I need help about:

```
<a class="wsite-com-continue-shopping" href="/">
                <span class="caret">◀</span>
                Continue Shopping</a>
```

I'd like to have the word "Continue Shopping" translated to another language here.

Comment: You really shouldn't use CSS this way. While you could potentially hack your way through it, it would be an SEO and accessibility nightmare and would be extremely difficult to maintain, especially for someone who isn't intimately familiar with the DOM and CSS.

Comment: Can you add anything to this page? You would probably want Javascript not CSS, but if you can not access those items in your editor, you may not be able to add JS.

Comment: What does "having my website edited in one of the web editors" mean? CSS is absolutely not meant for this.

Comment: You want Javascript or/and PHP, *not* CSS. CSS is a styling language, not a programming language.

Comment: @Roope what I mean by "wed editors" is services such as Wix, Weebly, Webs etc. (I wouldn't want to name it specifically here, as I consider it unethical).

Comment: @MatthewDarnell I do realize the consequences, but I also realize I'm loosing lots of potential customers who refuse to use the system because it is not in their native language

Comment: If it's your site, why don't you have access to edit the HTML, add javascript, translate the site properly. Doing things with CSS like this means that none of that language stuff will get indexed by search engines, so even given your goals, it's a really bad solution.

Comment: @hopkins-matt Yes, I can add any of the files I want, you have any solution for this problem that uses javascript?

Comment: @MatthewDarnell how do you propose I do that? The website is mine, but it was created in one of the website building services on the web

Comment: Sounds like you need a customized website with your own web hosting, 'web-builder-ready' sites such as Wix are really for people who don't know an inch of HTML or CSS. Translation is simple (especially with PHP/Javascript)- you provide multiple versions of the translated text for each language- but web-builder websites such as Wix are too restrictive.

Comment: The service that you are using is a technical property of your site, and therefore somewhat critical to understanding the situation that you are in, and thus to helping you. Not unethical, really.

Comment: You made a website on http://www.website.com/, didn't you? Those services really aren't for building sites like this, and a JS solution would also not work for SEO. You really need to get into the backend code, detect language and output the correct language in the correct context.

Comment: @cybermonkey Yes, I need my own made website with my own hosting. Funny thing is that we have our own hosting, but we use it for emails. Transferring a website like this with over 100 of products on it to my own hosting would result in a nightmare, as the website building platform I'm using lets me give my co-workers easy access to managing of orders and shipping, and as well an easy access to analytics

Comment: An ecommerce software such as Magneto offers the same thing..

Comment: @Roope website was made with Weebly. I consider unethical for this to say as it might give a wrong impression of Weebly as a platform, but as the time is passing by I'm waiting for more support from Weebly superiors (I haven't yet received the final NO regarding to my issue, so I wouldn't want people to misunderstand the situation and consider Weebly a bad platform).

Comment: @cybermonkey I'm yet to learn advanced CSS and javascript. After i'm done with that, I will surely switch to my own edited website and Magento for an ecommerce, as I already tried their services at my friend's website and I consider them quite amazing :)

Comment: I don't think any of us see those tools as being a bad or good platform. They just have many limitations, multi-language translations being one of them, and probably will not work for your needs.

Comment: As long as you are stating facts, there's nothing unethical in it. And if this is a feature of the platform/service for real, then so be it. Nothing unethical, merely technical facts.

Comment: I highly appreciate all of your time fellows :) as I said, I'm expecting a final answer from Weebly superiors and hope for it to be helpful :)

Comment: @AlenŠimunic I can already tell you what their answer is going to be: 'Our service isn't designed for your usage level, so you'll need your own website with your own files.'.

Comment: @cybermonkey I refuse to believe so, as I'll gladly pay extra to have this issue solved and have my website translated in other languages I need :)

Comment: @AlenŠimunic Are you wanting it to always be translated or for the users to have the option of translate content?

Comment: @AlenŠimunic I've told you already: Wix is a platform for users without your level of experience. They'll try their best to keep you (especially if you're a paying customer), but custom Javascript is a security loophole and isn't possible on their platform.

Comment: Although not HTML/CSS/JS/PHP, the [answer I provided here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442149/detect-os-language-provide-different-language-dropdown-menu/27442697#27442697) should help you to understand the logic required for making available multiple languages on your website.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Short Answer: CSS isn't really designed for that sort of thing, you should probably look into a different solution. It is technically possible though.

---

You can actually set the content of CSS elements, but only `:before` and `:after` elements that are applied to the element. Therefore, if you have an element like

```
<td id="HelloText">Hello</td>
```

You can have it "translated" to Spanish with

```
#HelloText
{
    font-size: 0; // hides existing text
}

#HelloText:after
{
    font-size: 14px;
    content: "Hola";
}
```

This isn't really ideal though, because this adds more bloat to your CSS and HTML (your page is loading the English and other language text), and this won't really work well for large blocks of text, or formatted text, eg text with `<span>` tags or `<a>` tags.

Not to mention that this is *really* bad for SEO. A search engine crawler normally just looks at a page's HTML (and sometimes Javascript) to index the page, never at what is in the CSS files attached to the page.

You definitely want to talk to the programmers that have access to the HTML to see if you can implement a server-side or Javascript solution for translation.

Comment: For now, they refuse to give me any access to the specific source code I need to alter and as well refuse to have that edited by themselves (probably everyone using the web building platform uses the same files). Is javascript maybe a better solution to solve this problem? I'm getting desperate about what to do here, as it's been weeks since I started seeking for a proper solution. And yes, I do realize what this is doing to the SEO, but my hands are tied as the customers we supply appreciate only their native language.

Comment: If you really cannot access the HTML output, Javascript is your only way to go. You would have to embed translation Javascript for a set language, then I'd recommend having the Javascript read from a JSON file that specifies what elements get what changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge of javascript is none. Could you refer to any tutorials for this specific solution?

Comment: Stating that translating a website with CSS is technically possible is like stating photo editing is possible with Notepad. Technically, they're both true. But before asking questions on SO he needs to become a programmer. Right now he's convinced the web is flat and that one can see all its corners if they stayed in the middle. Your answer is missleading him, as he doesn't have the means to weigh it yet.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel That wouldn't work for CEO...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I can agree with you. Currently I only have knowledge of neccessary HTML and neccessary CSS, no more than that. However, I'm a daily learner of both and planning to learn javascript as soon as I'm done with HTML and CSS. This topic could result in many of novices such as myself become misleaded. I just hope it won't.

Comment: Alen. The only advice you should have gotten on this page is: "*Hire a programmer. As of now, you are not grasping elementary concepts of web technologies and, even if you do find a solution, you are highly more likely to do a lot more harm than good to the website itself.*" **You are trying to fly a plane but you never even set foot in one before.** And I'm not exagerating. If you have an urgent need regarding a website, you should hire a professional, even if only for a theoretical discussion, not for the job itself. **Than you will be able to take *a better decision.***

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thank you for advice Andrei, it is highly appreciated as well as is the time all of you have spent here :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for someone with limited knowledge of javascript would be to either hire someone or use Google Translate.

Google offers a dropdown translation menu that you can add to your site. This will only translate the page after someone interacts with the dropdown unless they visit your page using a specially crafted URL that includes `#googtrans(TARGET_LANG_CODE)` on the end of the URL.

Learn more about Google Translate: https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601

If you want it always (or almost always) translated, you would want to have someone write a script for you. This script would automatically translate the elements you mentioned to the one language you choose. There are plenty of freelancers who could do something like this fairly affordably. However, keep in mind that if a user has javascript disabled most solutions will not work.

Comment: I'd love an explanation for the down vote

Comment: Google Translate is quite bad for some languages, matt. For mine is, for example. I'm assuming whoever voted you down was someone who doesn't consider GT a decent solution for translating a website, even though, for someone without any programming knowledge your solution is much better than none. Or maybe someone considered providing an answer to a an off-topic Q is bad altogether. I initially didn't think much of your answer, but I'm realizing it probably has the highest practical value from all given so far. +1

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I agree that GT is not a great solution, but it is probably the best solution for the skill set of the OP. Any other solution would likely involve dedicating time to learn or hiring someone. Thanks!